# Remove all JavaScript from an HTML page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, screen-scraping, nokogiri

I've tried using the `Sanitize` gem to clean a string which contains the HTML of a website.

It only removed the `<script>` tags, not the JavaScript inside the script tags.

What can I use to remove the JavaScript from a page?

Comment: Do you also want to remove all `on*` attributes?

Answer (score 13):

```
require 'open-uri'      # included with Ruby; only needed to load HTML from a URL
require 'nokogiri'      # gem install nokogiri   read more at http://nokogiri.org

html = open('http://stackoverflow.com')              # Get the HTML source string
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(html)                            # Parse the document

doc.css('script').remove                             # Remove <script>…</script>
puts doc                                             # Source w/o script blocks

doc.xpath("//@*[starts-with(name(),'on')]").remove   # Remove on____ attributes
puts doc                                             # Source w/o any JavaScript
```

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea if your intention is to prevent XSS attacks. There are all sorts of edge cases you're missing. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 6):

I am partial to the [Loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah) gem. Modified from an example in the docs:

```
1.9.3p0 :005 > Loofah.fragment("<span onclick='foo'>hello</span> <script>alert('OHAI')</script>").scrub!(:prune).to_s
 => "<span>hello</span> "
```

You might be interested in the [ActiveRecord extensions](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah-activerecord) Loofah provides.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that `Sanitize` has an option built in (just not well documented)...

```
Sanitize.clean(content, :remove_contents => ['script', 'style'])
```

This removed all script and style tags (and their content) as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to add the `sanitize` gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'sanitize`
```

Then `bundle`

And then you can do `Sanitize.clean(text, remove_contents: ['script', 'style'])`

Answer (score 0):

I use this regular expression to get rid of `<script>` and `</script>` tags in embeded content and just make the tags vanish. It also gets rid of things like `< script>` or `< /script >` ...etc... i.e. added whitespace.

`post.content = post.content.gsub(/<\s*script\s*>|<\s*\/\s*script\s*>/, '')`

Answer (score 0):

## remove all script tags

```
html_content = html_content.gsub(/<script.*?>[\s\S]*<\/script>/i, "")
```

[source](http://house9.blogspot.com/2010/01/ruby-regex-to-remove-script-tags.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all `<script>` tags and their contents:

```
regex = /<\s*s\s*c\s*r\s*i\s*p\s*t.*?>.*?<\s*\/\s*s\s*c\s*r\s*i\s*p\s*t\s*>|<\s*s\s*c\s*r\s*i\s*p\s*t.*?>|<\s*\/\s*s\s*c\s*r\s*i\s*p\s*t\s*>/im
while text =~ regex
  text.gsub!(regex, '')
end
```

This will even take care of cases like:

```
<scr<script></script>ipt>alert('hello');</scr</script>ipt>
<script class='blah'  >alert('hello');</script  >
```

And other tricks. It won't, however, remove JavaScript that is executed via `onload=` or `onclick=`.